# Include error on the predictor from mean and asymetric credible interval

Tags: r, bayesian, measurement-error, brms, capture-mark-recapture

I am doing non-linear models with brms. My model is :

```
bf(y ~ (I * (N * K)^b)/area_ha, 
                 I0 ~ 1,
                 b ~ 1,
                 nl = T,
                 family = gaussian())
```

I want to include the error on the predictor N. N is a population size estimated from mark recapture (schnabel). For each data point I have an estimate and a 95% credible interval for N. To include the error on the predictor (N), I need the distribution for the observed N. I have two questions: 1) The CI is asymetric and I am not sure what type of distribution I should use. I was thinking lognormal or beta, but I am not sure. 2) How do I find the parameters of the distribution function from only the estimate and CI?

Comment: Most likely you will need some parametric form for $p(N)$, your measurement error model of the population estimate. Maybe more details about the mark-recapture model would help.